# Where can Goldenfry be found in the Elder's Recess?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

The ingame Monster Field Guide lists the Elder's Recess as one habitat where the Goldenfry is found, but I have never, in 600 hours, seen any fishing spots in the Elder's Recess with Goldenfry in them.

Where can I find Goldenfry in the Elder's Recess?